# Finding patterns in a string

Tags: javascript, strings

I'm trying to find patterns of different length in a given string. How can I improve it? Are there problems?

```
function find(pattern,str) {
   var  arr = [];
   for (i= 0;i<str.length;i++) {
      if(pattern== str.slice(i,pattern.length+i)) {
       arr.push([i,pattern.length-1+i]);
     };
  };
   if(!arr.length) { return false;} else { return arr;};
};


find('abfd','abfdffdabfdfaffab');
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't use a regular expression?

Comment: no, it is every thing from scratch, the question was write a function that finds a pattern of different size in a string and returns the beginning and ending index.

Comment: Or just use `.indexOf()` and slice only when you find a match.

Comment: This is one of those optimization questions where the right answer is almost certainly "don't try".  The only obvious issue I see: you'll never find a match when (pattern.length+i > str.length) so there's no point wasting effort checking there.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two different ways of doing this, one using repeated calls to `.indexOf()` and one using repeated calls with a regex to `.exec()`.  The regex solution requires the pattern argument to be a regex compatible string or an actual RegExp object with the `g` flag on it.

The `.indexOf()` option should be much faster than what you have since it avoids repeated `.slice()` operations and `.indexOf()` as a library function should be faster than your own variation.  The regex option is a lot more flexible since you can search for phrases that match a regular expression.

```js
function find1(pattern,str) {
    var  arr = [];
    var i = 0;
    while ((i = str.indexOf(pattern, i)) > -1) {
        // got a match starting at i
        arr.push([i, i + pattern.length - 1]);
        i++;
    }
    return arr.length ? arr : false;
};

function find2(pattern,str) {
    var  arr = [], matches;
    if (typeof pattern === "string") {
     pattern = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
    } else if (!(pattern instanceof RegExp)) {
        throw new Error("pattern must be string or RegExp object");
    }
        
    while (matches = pattern.exec(str)) {
        arr.push([matches.index, matches.index + matches[0].length - 1]);
    }
    return arr.length ? arr : false;
};


document.getElementById("run1").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var results = find1('abfd','abfdffdabfdfaffab');
    log(results);
});

document.getElementById("run2").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var results = find2('abfd','abfdffdabfdfaffab');
    log(results);
});

function log(x) {
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(x) + "<br>";
    document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

```html
<button id="run1">Run .indexOf()</button> 
<button id="run2">Run regex</button><br><br>
```

Comment: Note that the `RegExp` behaves quite differently from the original code, which treats all characters in the "pattern" literally.

Answer (score 1):

Creating string slices in every iteration is probably not efficient.

You don't need to iterate until `str.length`, it would be enough until `str.length - pattern.length`. This also helps with nonsense input where the pattern string is longer than the searched string.

The solution of [@jfriend](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/6502/jfriend00) using `indexOf` takes care of both of these issues.

Another important issue is the return value. It's not great to return two kinds of values: boolean or array. It's a strange design, and it makes the function harder to use. For example I cannot simply iterate over the results, I have to check for the value for first. I suggest to return an empty array when they're are no matches. The result will be much cleaner and easier to use. Note that an empty array is *falsy* in JavaScript, so you can still use it in a boolean context.

The word pattern may evoke a regular expression or something with wildcards. If recommend another name that suggests better a literal string. Perhaps "fragment".